# Laravel advice on unzipping files on s3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5, unzip

I have a form where users upload a zip file. I am using the filesystem.

is it possible to upload the file to S3 and then unzip the file there?

**OR**

should i unzip the files first and then upload them to S3.

The zipped folder has lots of files in it (around 500-600 small files), so how does laravel work with such large amount of files? Will the system hault for the time the files are being uploaded or does it carry on in the background? like a queue

Answer (score 5):

No, AWS S3 will not provide you such functionality to unzip files on S3.

If you have EC2 instance within the same region, then Upload your zip files to EC2 and then move it S3 Unzipped.

Theres no charges between ec2 and s3 so ec2 can handle the unzipping and then write it out into your s3 bucket without additional transfer charges.

S3 will provide you just storage.

**EDIT- To transfer files from EC2 to S3**

You can use following command in AWS CLI. on you EC2

```
aws s3 cp myfolder s3://mybucket/myfolder --recursive
```

Here is the reference for it.
http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

For copying the files form the EC2 to S3 without interrupting the execution

- Create a script to transfer the files form the ec2 to s3. and after uploading files to the ec2. Use laravel queue to execute the script. so that User don't have to wait until files are being transfer.
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues

Comment: Thanks satish, but what about the time that the files are being uploaded to from ec2 to s3. Will the server pause to upload the files to s3 or is it going to be carried on in the background? like a queue.

Comment: You can create a function and after you upload something to ec2. just call that function using laravel queue.